# In rails how can I delegate to a class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```rb
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :due_date, :text

  def self.this_week
    where(:due_date => Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week)
  end
end

class Important < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  has_one :task, :as => :taskable, :dependent => :destroy

  delegate this_week, :to => :task
end
```

So far this delegate is not working as expected, when I try `Important.this_week`.  I get an error saying there is no method `this_week` defined for class...

Any ideas? Can I even delegate to a class method like this?  I may have another class or two extending `Task` in this way, so I'm curious how this works in a way that doesn't duplicate a bunch of code to each implementing class.

Comment: I think when you say `delegate this_week, :to => :task`, Rails takes that to mean "When someone calls `this_week` on an `Important`, return the value of that Important's `:task` object's `this_week` method." In other words, you're delegating to an instance method which isn't there.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're picking up the [ActiveSupport delegation core extension](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb).  The `delegate` helper defines an *instance* method for the current class so that instances of it delegate calls to some variable on *that instance*.

If you want to delegate at the class level, you need to open up the singleton class and set up the delegation there:

```
class Important < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  has_one :task, :as => :taskable, :dependent => :destroy

  class << self
    delegate :this_week, :to => :task
  end
end
```

But this assumes that `Important.task` is a reference to the `Task` class (which it is not)

Rather than relying on the delegation helper, which is just going to make your life difficult, I'd suggest explicit proxying here:

```
class Important < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  has_one :task, :as => :taskable, :dependent => :destroy

  class << self
    def this_week(*args, &block)
      Task.this_week(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 34):

Delegate a method to a class method, considering inheritance:

```
delegate :this_week, :to => :class
```

You can delegate to a specific class like so (see also Isaac Betesh's answer):

```
delegate :this_week, :to => :Task
```

Docs are available here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Comment: simple, clean! Very nice

Answer (score 12):

You can delegate a method to a constant--it's just case sensitive.  Also, the name of the method must be passed to `delegate` as a Symbol.

```
class Important < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :this_week, :to => :Task
  # Note ':this_week' instead of 'this_week'
  # Note 'Task' instead of 'task'
end
```