# Can I call a class method from another model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to call a class method (currently a scope) that uses an attribute from its parent (or belongs_to) model, but can't seem to get it working right.

My models:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address
  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  scope :is_near, lambda {|city| self(Venue.address).near(city, 20, :units => :km)}
end
```

I know the syntax is wrong, but I think that illustrates what I'm intending to do. I want to get the address of the venue and call another method on it. I need the scope in the `Event` class so I can chain other scopes together.

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: I assume `#address` is not a class method in `Venue` but an instance method?

Comment: `:address` is a string in the database. I can access it in my views using `<% = event.venue.address %>`

Comment: Can you post the definition of the `#near` method?

Comment: It's from the Ruby Geocoder gem, which I don't really know how to access. My understanding is that it uses the address attribute. I had it functioning before when the address was included in the `event` model with `self.near...` but I've moved it because it makes more sense for my application, specifically the user relations. https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Comment: Are you trying to get all the events within a 20km range of a specific venue?

Comment: Yup, exactly. The `city` variable is where the user passes in the city. Would a `delegate` work? I'm playing around with that now, but I can't tell if it doesn't accept scopes, or if it's not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36688/discussion-between-depa-and-bholt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `#address` is not a class method but an instance method, you won't be able to do what you want by using a scope.

If you want to get all the events within a 20km range of a venue, create these class methods in `Venue` instead:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.events_near_city(city)
    venues_near_city(city).map(&:events).flatten
  end

  private

  def self.venues_near_city(city)
    near(city, 20, :units => :km)
  end
end
```

Then call it by using `Venue.events_near_city(session[:city])` since, as you told me in chat, you're storing the city in the session.

Answer (score 0):

As you've defined it above, `address` is not a class method - it's an instance method. You would have to have an instance of venue (like you do in your view) to call it.

Comment: I had it working when `:address` was contained within the `event` class by using `self.near...` but I split the `venue` into its own class because it makes more sense for user associations. Since the scope is being called on an instance of `event`, which contains information about the `venue.address` is it possible to get that information somehow? Maybe changing the relations to `:inverse of`?

Comment: the problem is you're looking for multiple events - each of which has its own venue. I can see what you're trying to do... not sure I can help you figure out how to do it (sorry)... all I can do atm is point out why it's not working for you right now.

Comment: tl:dr: no - you can't do what you want that way, because you're after an instance - but you don't have an instance, you have the class. Can you show us how "near" is implemented?

Comment: It's from the Ruby Geocoder gem, which I don't really know how to access. My understanding is that it uses the address attribute. https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Answer (score 0):

Searching a bit more I found this page that answered the question in another way. This works better for me because it's simpler to call, and I can use it on various relations. [In rails how can I delegate to a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568211/in-rails-how-can-i-delegate-to-a-class-method)

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address

  def self.is_near(city)
    venues_near_city(city).map(&:events).flatten 
  end 
  private 
    def self.venues_near_city(city) 
      self.near(city, 20, :units => :km) 
    end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue

  class << self
    def is_near(*args, &block)
      Venue.is_near(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

And I call it with `event.is_near(session[:city])`

Comment: I couldn't get delegate to work because "The delegate helper defines an instance method for the current class so that instances of it delegate calls to some variable on that instance". This question explains it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568211/in-rails-how-can-i-delegate-to-a-class-method

Comment: Yes, but that question explains how to delegate at a class level.

Comment: I was trying to delegate a method from another class, but my understanding is that Rails defaults to delegate instances from inherited classes. What I change it to overrides that and now works. I'm pretty new to Rails, so if I'm mistaken I'd appreciate being corrected. I'd like to follow best practices and conventions!